# Electricity, and Gases

Tags: electrochemistry

Electricity can be conducted by an ionic compound dissolved in water, and when it is a liquid.  Can a gaseous ionic compound conduct electricity as well?  A metal cab conduct electricity when it is solid, and liquid.  Can a metal conduct electricity also as a gas?

Comment: It's rather about chemistry then physics.

Comment: Looks you should clarify. Do this: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/will-gaseous-ionic-compounds-be-free-moving-ions and comments under this http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37080/9961 answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

A gaseous ionic compound is a plasma.  And the answer is "yes", plasma conducts electricity very well, as seen with florescent lights.

Comment: Not exactly, in thermal plasma compounds are already decomposed. Low temperature vapors don't conduct electricity.

Comment: Define "low temperature".  I can touch the florescent lights in my house and not get burned by them.

Comment: There you have very low pressure and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission If there was simple piece of wire instead of electron emitter there wouldn't be light.

Comment: @Mithotron: Neon lights are a clear counterexample to what you are saying. No thermionic emission needed.

Comment: @CuriousOne There you have to apply breakdown voltage to ionize it. Yes, you can make plasma in various ways, but the point is that simply vaporizing NaCl using moderate temperature leads to molecules not ions. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/will-gaseous-ionic-compounds-be-free-moving-ions

Comment: @Mithoron: Nowhere does the OP's question contain that restriction. He is asking about gaseous ionic compounds, which are plasmas. Maybe you want to stick to the question.